# Unhandled Rejection (Error): Unauthorized using auth0

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, curl, auth0

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): Unauthorized
```

./node_modules/@auth0/auth0-spa-js/dist/auth0-spa-js.production.esm.js/</cr/</<
src/utils.ts:296

```
  293 |   ok
  294 | } = response;
  295 | 
> 296 | if (!ok) {
      | ^  297 |   const errorMessage =
  298 |     error_description || `HTTP error. Unable to fetch ${url}`;
  299 |   const e = <any>new Error(errorMessage);
```

Following this project:https://github.com/Prithwish10/Aucteria

I have tried double checking the pem file, testing the endpoint in aws(it works there) and sending a curl request(it failed to connect to api v2 or something ) and also using ngrok tunneling, but it made no difference

Strangely enough, it actually worked just once, but stopped working once I actually logged in.

Comment: Please, provide more information, e.g. which request at what points fail.
The most effective way to debug such errors is to look at `Auth0 > monitoring > logs`. (It would be better to add Auth0 logs to the question). 

Based on my experience problem could be due to grants (`Application > settings > advanced > grant types`)